# How can I know that the user interface in unity is changed by the c# code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am instantiating many gameobjects in the unity by the c# code... And then make the scrollbar value 0 in order to scroll to the last object...but the scroll is landing me in the middle. Because of that there is a delay between unity and c# code. so the scrollbar changes before all the objects are shown.

How can I know that the user interface in unity is changed totally and I now can scroll to the end using a listener or something that tells me that you can now make the scroll and all objects are ready in the user interface??

```
MakeMessages();
Scrollbar.value = 0;
```

The scrollbar value is 0 before all messages are appearing in unity, so it is changing to 0.5 then.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect Scrollbar value change with the [`Scrollbar.onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Scrollbar-onValueChanged.html). Register the event in the `OnEnable` function and un-register it the `OnDisable` function.

```
public Scrollbar sb;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Scrollbar Event
    sb.onValueChanged.AddListener(scollBarChanged);
}

//Called when Scrollbar value changes
private void scollBarChanged(float value)
{
    Debug.Log("Input Changed");
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Scrollbar Event
    sb.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: thank you...it works but now the scroll is refusing to go up...How can I fix this problem??

Comment: The code in my answer cannot prevent scroll from working or scrolling. This problem seems to unrelated. Make sure you have EventSystem in your scene. If still not working please create new question and describe the exact issue in it

Comment: I think that the problem is related. Whenever I pull the scroll to go to the top, the listener is called and it set the scroll value to 0. so I cannot go up anymore

Comment: But my the code in my answer is not setting the scroll value at-all. This is your own modification. I thought you wanted to detect when the scroll value changes?

Comment: I wanna set the scroll to 0 when it's value it's changed in order to be at the bottom of the list

Comment: Just set it to 0 **once** in the `scollBarChanged` function.